# How few changes we make in controller class get dynamically reflected without redeploying?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have tried understanding this myself by googling but did not come across with anything satisfying.

I can describe my object for hunt with a simple example. I have a simple Spring MVC application deployed to my Tomcat server which has just one controller class with
`@RequestMapping`    annotation on only present method inside controller class. Now, i have added another `@requestMapping` annotation but at class level then obviously the URL will be changed for accessing the URL pattern relating to the `@RequestMapping` of the method of controller class.

Now, i do not need to restart the server to Test that the resource is not longer available with same URL pattern.

My current understanding is that when we deploy the application to our local server then that war file will be used for running that application. Then, how come the change we made in the controller class gets dynamically updated and we can test it without restarting the server and redeploying the new war file with latest change.

Also, I have given this particular scenario because I just come across with it.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why my question got a down vote? Is that because its a silly question? I would really appreciate if the person who down voted write something in comments so that at least i can learn from this or please take back down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally what ever you change in the code without change the shape/interface of the class can be handled by Hot Code Replacement (I think this is what you talk about -- debugging)

@Annotations are loaded statically and can not be changed during runtime.

You could use some cool classloader like JRebel or Spring-Loader to improve this ability. When you use spring-boot the developor tools reload the web context when you change something which is also also pretty cool

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was not aware as HCR is the reason for as i am a beginner. I have checked "https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F". So, is hot code replace applicable to java classes, not to jsp and other files?

Comment: JSPs are -- under the hood -- java classes (jasper compiles them to classes). You can change them also, but there are other concepts then HCR to make this work. Other resources like css, properties, html should work also but this is depending on your development setup/IDE

Comment: OK Great.I used to restart server everytime i change anything, but not anymore. Thanks again. accepted as answer and upvoted.